# Word Margins to Latex margins

Tags: margins

I have a word template that specificies

Top = 2.5cm
Bottom = 2.5cm
Inside = 4cm
Outside = 2cm
Gutter =0cm
Multiple pages = Mirror Margins

I am working with a book document class and trying to configure the margins that uses the above. I have looked at the wiki but to no avail. It will be printed doubled sided.

I currently have this in the code

```
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.74cm}
\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.74cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{24.62cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.5cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.46cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.46cm}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Try `\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,inner=4cm,outer=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}`.